# MAPI Property to get Junk Folder in Outlook 2007

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2007, mapi

I have a routine to get specific folders from an Outlook store:

```
// Property Tag of SentFolder
string propertyName = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x35E40102";

Outlook.Folders folders = store.GetRootFolder().Folders;
object entry = propertyAccesor.GetProperty(propertyName);
defaultFolderEntryID = propertyAccesor.BinaryToString(entry);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(defaultFolderEntryID))
{
   foreach (Outlook.Folder defaultFolder in folders)
   {
      if (defaultFolder.EntryID == defaultFolderEntryID)
      {
         folder = defaultFolder;
         break;
      }
      else
         Marshal.ReleaseComObject(defaultFolder);   
   }
}

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folders);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(store);
```

I have the property tag of the Sent Mail, Outbox and Deleted Items, but I cannot find the property tag of the Junk (or Spam) folder. Any body knows what is the value if it exists?

Thanks.-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use `Namespace/Store.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderJunk)`? Unless of course you are trying to open the Junk Mail folder of a delegate mailbox (you can use `Store.GetDefaultFolder` in Outlook 2010 or newer).

On the MAPI level, the entry id is stored in the `PR_ADDITIONAL_REN_ENTRYIDS` (`0x36D81102`) multivalued binary property; it is stored with the index of 4 (0 based). You can see it in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author - click IMAPIFolder button when the Inbox folder is selected).

Since Outlook 2007 does not expose the `Store` object (so that you can use `Store.GetDefaultFolder`), you can use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm) (I am also its author - any version of Outlook) - it exposes [RDOStore](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdostore.htm).`GetDefaultFolder` method in all versions of Outlook.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, `Store.GetDefaultFolder()` will work but for Outlook 2010 and newer as you said. I tried the `PR_ADDITIONAL_REN_ENTRYIDS` but it fails when executing `propertyAccesor.BinaryToString(propertyAccesor.GetProperty(propertyName))` saying `Type Mismatch. You must supply a binary value for conversion`. In fact, the object returned by `propertyAccesor.GetProperty(propertyName)` contains different array size from the other folders.

Comment: Got it! As you say it is stored in the fourth index of the array, so changing `defaultFolderEntryID = propertyAccesor.BinaryToString(entry);` to `defaultFolderEntryID = propertyAccesor.BinaryToString(entry[4]);` solved the issue and the Junk folder is retrieved. Thanks.